# How far back does the Campbell line go?

Tags: supernatural, genealogy

Sam and Dean Winchester get their hunting 'blood' from their mother's side (Ironically no their father's), and in season 6, Dean is told that he had ancestors '*hacking heads off vampires on the mayflower*'.

How far back does the family line go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The furthest back we have firm knowledge are to Samuel Campbell's parents (Sam and Dean's great grandparents). Samuel Campbell's first discovery of the supernatural happened when he was a teenager (he saw a wraith kill his friend). His parents subsequently tell him that he comes from a "long line of hunters", and bring him into the profession. That would *imply* that the Campbell line goes back at least three further generations, further back than Samuel's parents were alive, or they would *probably* have said "your grandfather was a hunter..." or similar.

This is shown in a spin-off novel called *Heart of the Dragon*, one of the tie-in novels for the series. As far as how reliable this information is, Kripke has said that they are not officially canon, in the sense that he (and presumably his successors) make no guarantee that future TV episodes won't contradict a novel. However, they are officially licensed Supernatural material, and their [canon status](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Canon) is largely subjective.

As far as I know, this is the only time any tie-in material goes back into Sam and Dean's family past any further than the televised episodes do.

Answer (score 0):

To date, this is unknown. His grandfather's boasts shouldn't be taken as fact, at the very least they are embellished greatly, but more likely it's just BS so that he can sound tough and knowledgeable. Future seasons of the show could reveal more, but since (angelic) time travel is limited, it's difficult to imagine how the show might depict that. They do flashbacks once in awhile, but tend to shy away from doing so needlessly.

Other forms of time travel may not be as limited, but they've sort of burnt that bridge.

Comment: Is there any canon outside of the show we could draw from?

Comment: I know of none, save maybe a few Kripke qutoes at conventions. It's doubtful he's commented on such a minor detail though.